# Mongoose behaving in surprise manner

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am working on nodejs mongoose for connecting to MongoDB, but I need 2 different connections to 2 different MongoDBs sitting on two different locations, what I did is as below :

```
global.otherDB = mongooseGlobal.createConnection(uri_1/DB1, { db: { safe: true });
global.mongoose = mongooseGlobal.connect(uri_2/DB2, { db: { safe: true });
```

Now where ever I need to connect to uri_2/DB2, I use mongoose and where ever I need to connect to uri_1/DB1, I use otherDB, now here is what is happening surprisingly,

1. Whenever I try to write or access DB1, it is creating or accessing collections available at uri_2/DB1 instead of uri_1/DB1, which is very surprising.
2. I didn't have any path of uri_2/DB1 while creating any mongo connection, how is it possible that DB1 is getting created at uri_2 instead of uri_1

Please give inputs.

Comment: seems your are creating the connection to DB1 and the overriding it using connect

Comment: Doesn't sound possbile scenario as how would you explain uri_2/DB1 ?

Comment: And let me tell you one interesting fix for this as well which I tried and worked, just remove { db: { safe: true } from global.otherDB and things worked as expected.

Comment: You need to show how you are actually using the connections. They shoul d be separately instatiated on different models. If however you are trying to "re-use" models and "swapping" the connection, then that would explain the behavior, as this is not the correct way to use it.

Comment: I am using connections as in one file I am using module.exports = otherDB.model("otherModelSchema", otheModel), otherModel holds mongoose schema, while for other case I using mongoose.model("db2Schema", db2Schema). But really do not understand why removing options  from otherDB solved the problem.